# The fastest way to populate a In Memory Data Grid Hazelcast

Tags: java, caching, datagrid, hazelcast, in-memory

What is the fastest way to populate a Hazelcast Data Grid. Reading through documentation I can see couple of variants:

1. Use multithreading and IMap.set
2. Use multithreading and IMap.putAll
3. Use a Distributed Execution in order to start populating the grid from all participants.

My performance benchmark shows that IMap.putAll is faster than IMap.Set.  But it is stated in the Hazelcasty Documentation that IMap.putAll does not come with guarantees that everything will be inserted atomically.

Can someone clarify a little bit about what would be the fastest way to populate a data grid with data ?

Is variant number 3 good ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would see the same three options. Anyhow as you mentioned, option two does not guarantee that everything was put into the map atomically but if you just load data and wait for all threads to finish loading data using IMap::putAll you should be fine.

Apart from that IMap::set would be the alternative. In any case you want to multithread the loading process. I would play around a bit with different thread numbers and loading data from a client is normally recommended to keep nodes free for storage operations.

I personally never benchmarked your third option, anyhow it would be possible as well. Just not sure it is worth the additional work.

How much data do you want to load that you're concerned it could be slow? Do you already know that loading is slow? Do you use Java Serialization (this is a huge performance killer)? Do you use indexes (those have to be generated while putting data)?

There's normally a lot of optimizations to apply to speed up, not only, data loading but also normal operation.

Comment: Hei thanks for the answere. I was more or less wondering if there is ant point testing optionopinion 3. And if there is a forth option. As to your question the outsourcing team is claiming that their performance is worse compared to a store to DB. So far i have seen they use IMAP::put Instead of IMAP::putAll. Serialization looks good. They are ising Spring batch to popplate the grid in paralel.I will check more today.

Comment: Hello again, I just saw the source code. It is using Transactional Map and putAll method is missing from the implementation of the TransactionalMap. How is this changing the things ? How can we put in bulks into this transactional Map ?

Comment: Hello, there is an interesting side effect observed when using TransactionalMap. The performance is highly dependent on the amount of objects inserted in the MAP. When inserted chunk size is 1000 the speed is significantly lower compared to chunk size 250. Why is that ? Is there any way to improve ?

Comment: I would suspect because of the additional overhead to sync the transaction, anyhow not a real idea. Why you bother using a transactional map anyways? If you want fast loading I can't believe your faster using TransactionalMap::putAll over IMap::set / IMap::put / IMap::putAsync loops.

Comment: I have not checked the putAsynch but I will double check my results of putAll vs put/set . In a single thread my impression was putAll is faster.

Comment: I agree that transactions are not needed. We will go for the IMap interface.

Comment: Well I am running 3 local instances of HAzelcast. I increased the receiving and sending buffers. Tried IMap:putAll vs IMap:putAsync, the performance for me appears to be similar when I measure every 1000 insertions. With putAll looks like performing very slightly better. The heap size is preinitialized for all nodes to be big so that there is no GC kicking in. I was expecting more speed from putAsync.